# Do I need any special device to use an AP over POE with a home router?

Tags: wireless-access-point, power-over-ethernet

I am setting up a small network for my office, I have a ZTE F660 router which is provided by my ISP and I am considering buying a couple of LINKSYS LAPAC1200 with POE access points. My question is, do I need my current router to support this feature? or I just plug it and it's working? Do I need another devices to power my AP with POE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZTE F660 doesn't serve PoE. You need an AC/DC to PoE converter/injector as [TL-POE150S](http://www.tp-link.com/sa/products/details/cat-4794_TL-POE150S.html) or a PoE switch between the router and APs.

Comment: Let's assume I have a PoE switch and I plug the APs to it, using PoE will slow their performance? or will it be the same as using the APs with the power adapter?

Comment: PoE doesn't decrease performance. If you can afford it, use CAT 6. Here you have more technical information of how PoE works: http://www.rhyshaden.com/eth_poe.htm

Comment: Thanks, can you answer this question? http://superuser.com/q/1051804/569436

Comment: OK, I'll try...