# Which TIA/EIA-568 terminations I need to plug an AP with PoE to a switch?

Tags: networking, rj-45, power-over-ethernet, twisted-pair

I have understood that I have to use the same termination (wheter it is 568A or 568B) in the cable when it is intended to plug a PTE device such as a PC, printer, etc. to a PCE device such as a router or a switch. And to use a crossover cable (with 568A and 568B in each termination) when it is intended to connect the same kind of devices (Which i think it is my case).
But then i was looking at [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet#Pinouts) and i got confused on how do I need to plug my switch and my access point when using Power over Ethernet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T568B is "US standard" because it is compatible with older telephone gear. But I'm not from US and I've always used B...

If you have already some networks devices provided IE by your ISP, take a look at the cables and use the same termination and you will not have any problem.

You'll not need a crossover cable if you don't have old devices, because they where commonly intended for ad-hoc nets. Nowadays, ethernet equipment is created with a widely used option called Auto-MDIX (automatic medium-dependent interface crossover). This technology detects whether you need a crossover cable or a straight-through cable, and it automatically configures the network interface card accordingly.